# How do I find the region of integration (in cartesian coordinates) of the following integral?

Tags: integration

I need to define the integral

$$\iint_Rxdydx,$$

where the region $R$ is represented by the following graph:

[image]

I understand x must limited as: $0\le x\le1$, but I'm not sure how y is limited.

I tried limiting it as: $-x\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}$, because following the equation of the circle, $x^2+y^2\le1^2$, but wolfram is giving the following representation:

[image]

, which is not correct. What is the correct region of integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is correct for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ as intersection of circle and $y = -x$ is,

$x^2 + (-x)^2 = 1 \implies x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. As you are on the right side of y-axis, intersection is at $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

For $\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \leq x \leq 1$, $y$ is bound both below and above by the circle. So,

$ - \sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have two regions. For $0\le x\le \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ you have $-x\le y\le \sqrt{1-x^2}$. For $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\le x\le 1$ you get $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\le y\le \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Alternatively, one can use polar coordinates. That would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Mit den Kreiskoordinaten $x=r\cdot cos\phi;y=r\cdot sin\phi$ und dem Flächenelement $dxdy=rdrd\phi$ ergibt das: $\int_{\phi=-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{r=0}^1 rcos\phi drd\phi$